# Why would static function prototype arguments in C++ be surrounded by ARGS()?

Tags: c++, compilation, prototype

I'm attempting to work with someone else's C++ code, and am flummoxed by a strange syntax that is preventing the code from compiling.

In many of the .c files they provide, they have prototypes for static functions, which look like this:

```
static DdNode * extraZddIsopCoverRandom  ARGS((DdManager * dd, DdHashTable * table, DdNode * bOn, DdNode * bOnDc, int * pPerm, int cVar));
static int * extraGenerateRandomPermutation ARGS((int nVars));
static void     cuddHashTableQuitZdd2(DdHashTable * hash);
```

Not all of them, but a solid chunk of the functions have that ARGS() syntax around the arguments, which causes the compiler to spit out an error message like this:

```
extraZddIsop.c:50: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ARGS’
```

I assume that something also related is the fact that all of the functions with ARGS() give this error, too:

```
extraZddIsop.c: At top level:
extraZddIsop.c:1217: error: conflicting types for ‘extraZddIsopCoverRandom’
extraZddIsop.c:161: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘extraZddIsopCoverRandom’ was here
extraZddIsop.c:1500: error: conflicting types for ‘extraGenerateRandomPermutation’
extraZddIsop.c:155: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘extraGenerateRandomPermutation’ was here
```

The errors disappear when I remove the ARGS() around those blocks, and it seems to be compiling, but with so many of them, I'm worried I must be messing something up horribly that will cause later errors by removing them. This also seems to be an absolutely impossible problem to Google, because "args" is used in other contexts so often. Does anyone have any idea why that might be there?

I can give the definitions of the functions on request, but I'm mostly just wondering what this ARGS() thing could possibly be, so I expect they aren't relevant.

Comment: Files ending with `.c` are not C++ files, but ***C*** source files.

Comment: As for your problem, someone probably missed to include the file that defines the `ARGS` macro. Search for it in the header files provided. And I'm sure it's a macro, because it's not uncommon to see old C code with a macro like that (typically named `ARGS` or similar), to handle the difference between old K&R and "new" ANSI standard C function prototypes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is probably meant to be defined on the command line, e.g. `gcc -DARGS(X)=X`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a trick to cater to ancient pre-standard C compilers. These don't handle function prototypes (typed parameter lists in particular). Thus, the macro can be defined as:

```
#define ARGS(list) ()
```

... after which all of the functions are declared as `Something func();`, which a C compiler recognizes as a function taking unspecified arguments. For other C (and C++) compilers, `ARGS` can be defined as:

```
#define ARGS(list) list
```

... which just strips off the `ARGS()` and leaves the prototype untouched. That's what you should do if you're using a C compiler from this millenium, or a C++ compiler.

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks! I have no idea why their package assumed it was already defined, but that's what I get for grabbing code off of random faculty webpages from over a decade ago.